# How to increase heap space for a Python library based on Java?

Tags: java, python, jvm, heap-memory, py4j

I'm a Python user and I'm struggling with a java-based library (lolopy, https://pypi.org/project/lolopy/). In particular, I should increase the heap space following what the authors say in the documentation:

"*Setting the maximum memory footprint for the JVM running the machine learning calculations can be achieved by **setting the LOLOPY_JVM_MEMORY environment variable**. The value for LOLOPY_JVM_MEMORY is used to set the maximum heap size for the JVM (see Oracle’s documentation for details). For example, “4g” allows lolo to use 4GB of memory*".

Having never used Java, I have no idea what to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to set the heap space directly. Read the instructions again. You need to change the LOLOPY_JVM_MEMORY env var, which will be used to set max heap for you. So the real question is whether you know how to set environment variables on your OS. Your problem isn't specific to Java at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a new env variable:

> Name: LOLOPY_JVM_MEMORY
>
> Value: 4g (or any other value you need)

Here is simple manual how to do it if you don't know. Just change PATH to LOLOPY_JVM_MEMORY: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

But it has nothing with Java. It just a simple environment variable

[EDIT]

Ok, this tutorial is much better: https://www.poftut.com/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-linux-windows-bsd-and-macosx/

Comment: I have done what you suggested, creating a variable LOLOPY_JVM_MEMORY with 2g as value, but I get the following error when I run the Python code: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'Error occurred during initialization of VM\n'`. (On my computer I have 16GB of RAM).

Comment: Are you sure that you have Java installed and added to PATH? Do you java JAVA_HOME created?

Comment: I get the error running the Python code `from lolopy.learners import RandomForestRegressor` and `model = RandomForestRegressor()`. My variables are LOLOPY_JVM_MEMORY=2g, Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath and JAVA_HOME=C:\Program File (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251. I have tried also with JRE_HOME=C:\Program File (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251 and with JRE_HOME=C:\Progra~2\Java\jre1.8.0_251, but they give the same error.

Comment: I think you have to install JDK instead of JRE:

Development
Lolopy requires Python >= 3.6, Java JDK >= 1.8, and Maven to be installed on your system when developing lolopy.

Comment: I have done exactly what you said (I think), but the error is the same. I have realized that in one of the lolopy files (i.e., loloserver.py) there is this code: `if 'LOLOPY_JVM_MEMORY' in os.environ:`// `java_options.append('-Xmx' + os.environ['LOLOPY_JVM_MEMORY'])`. I have tried to modify it directly, replacing with  `java_options.append('-Xmx' + '2g')`, but I get the same error.

Comment: I think it a different problem. Maybe you set this value to big. Try smaller values (maybe 1g). Do you have 64 bit jdk? Could you please run `java -version` and copy its output here?

Comment: `java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)`        Effectively, trying 1g it works, but I need more. Why, if I have 16GB available?

Comment: I think you have 32-bit Java installed. If it is located in `c:\Program Files (x86)` than it is 32-bit version. And it cannot allocate more than about 1.5gb. If that's the issue, please install 64-bit Java